# MongoDB transform array of objects into array of field values

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I got a field which is an Array of objects inside another array of object in below format

```
{
 id: '1234567',
 listOfSettings: [{
  name: 'setting1',
  listOfObjects: [{name: 'object1',id:'111'}, {name: 'object2', id: '112'}]
 }, {
  name: 'setting2',
  listOfObjects: [{name: 'object2',id:'113'}, {name: 'object3', id: '114'}]
 }]
}
```

I want to convert it with a Mongo update query into something like:

```
{
  id: '1234567',
  listOfSettings:[{
   name: 'settings1',
   listOfObjects:['111', '112']
  }, {
   name: 'settings2',
   listOfObjects:['113', '114']
  }]
}
```

I know I can use the $set option to update the content and $fieldname to specify the field to obtain values, but not sure how I can achieve it in case of nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Agg pipeline:

```
[{"$project"=>
   {"listOfSettings"=>
     {"$map"=>
       {"input"=>"$listOfSettings",
        "as"=>"x",
        "in"=>
         {"$mergeObjects"=>
           ["$$x",
            {"listOfObjects"=>
              {"$map"=>
                {"input"=>"$$x.listOfObjects",
                 "as"=>"y",
                 "in"=>"$$y.id"}}}]}}}}}]

[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('60aee7b82c97a61504d9b01a'),
  "listOfSettings"=>
   [{"name"=>"setting1", "listOfObjects"=>["111", "112"]},
    {"name"=>"setting2", "listOfObjects"=>["113", "114"]}]}]
```

Comment: is there any other way to approach it out of aggregation pipeline?